# Can we have "belongs on some other stackexchange site" as an option when voting to close?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

I just asked a question on Stack Overflow, and then ended up migrating it to a Stack Exchange site other than the ones in trilogy. But now I can't say "belongs on miscellaneous non-trilogy stackexchange site" when voting to close. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- On all non-Meta sites in the network, you can now vote to migrate to any one of (up to) 5 predefined target sites, one of which is always the per-site Meta.
- If none of the available target sites are suitable, you can still close as simply "off topic."
- Diamond moderators can migrate a question to *any* site in the network (flag for moderator attention and state your case).
- The predefined migration paths are SE staff controlled, but if a community can make a convincing argument to add/remove sites from the list, the list can be changed.

Answer (score 5):

Probably best to simply close as `Off Topic` for now.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Anyone wishing to assist me in closing it can do so here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723958/how-can-i-save-bioperl-sequence-nested-features-in-genbank-or-embl-format

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't have the rep on SO to help with that, best of luck.