# Flag question "Belongs on other stackexchange site" needs other ui. I missed an option

Tags: feature-request, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

When flagging https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941749/how-to-boost-module-cron-run-or-save as *off topic* on SO (following [Which questions should be on-topic on Drupal Answers, but not on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87719/which-questions-should-be-on-topic-on-drupal-answers-but-not-on-stack-overflow) since is didn't involve any programming) I was missing the "*belongs on **drupal.stackexchange.com***" option.

The "only" options were:

- is off topic
- meta.stackoverflow.com
- serverfault.com
- superuser.com
- webmasters.stackexchange.com
- programmers.stackexchange.com

Having a couple of suggestions left me with the impression that I should be explicit when flagging, and made me backtrack and leave an apologetic "it needs ♦ moderator attention" comment.

### With so many sites coming out of beta, how can we improve this UI?

### Even more options?

I think an extra option with a select box with all sites out of beta (perhaps minus the options that already have their own radio), could fix this. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104604/more-belongs-on-close-moving-options-please) for a mockup along these lines.

I'm not for removing the radio's with the best guesses of the system, just an extra option for when the guessing fails.

As @lix commented on the question, having [all sites enumerated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites) is impractical. But I still think having some pre-guessed options (4?) and a "catch-all" selectbox-option, could work.

Like suggested to [*More* options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110996/171231), this is growing more and more above the `"Don't Make Me Think" barrier` and might just **not** work. A huge select is not any different from a long list of radio-buttons.

### Fewer options?

One of the related questions I didn't find until @bart pointed them out was [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79961/171231) that moderators already have a great migration UI (see also @fabian's comment or [Should some communities have more than 4 migration targets?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118685/should-some-communities-have-more-than-4-migration-targets) for a screenshot of the Vote-to-close dialog).

That being the case, I'd opt for just 2 options

- off-topic
- belongs on another SE site. If you *know* it is a better fit for that site, please leave a comment on the question roughly following this template: `Hi $name, I think your question would be a better fit on $site. This site deals with $topic. Please don't cross-post, a mod will migrate it for you.`

### Expanding the faq?

Given all the linked questions I think I'm not the only one confused by the current UI.
If an intuitive UI is impossible, we could at least improve the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#flagging), to prevent [yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96013/off-topic-site-list) [another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117581/site-list-for-it-does-not-belong-here-flag-proposed-changes) duplicate post on meta, like this one. The [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84974/171231) to the original feature request [Can we have "belongs on some other stackexchange site" as an option when voting to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48662/can-we-have-belongs-on-some-other-stackexchange-site-as-an-option-when-voting) is short, yet already clarifying.

Or perhaps, that's one of meta's functions, and we should change the [Analytical](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1306/analytical)-badge to "Read every question on meta" ;-)

Comment: It would be impractical to include EVERY SE site in that list... If you really feel strongly about where the post needs to be migrated to then give a custom message with the flag explaining why and to where you feel this question should be migrated.

Comment: Um... you can just edit your post - you don't have to post a new answer to add information.

Comment: @lix just trying to keep the separation between problem and solution. And I ended up writing a custom message in the end. But that required me to go down the options and then backtrack up again. I took that effort, but others might be tempted to just pick "off topic" and leave more work to the moderators. But I'm not a moderator, so I don't know if that's really a problem.

Comment: You can still suggest the solution in your original post.  It **is** a feature request, so you should detail what feature you are requesting in your post.  Your heart is in the right place - but that is simply not the way things are usually done here :)  Take a look at some of the other [feature requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Lix is right. As it stands, your question is not a feature request. Your "answer" would make it one. That being said, I think this has been discussed many times before without much success. For example [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited).

Comment: @bar - yes, although I couldn't find a link to a relevant "status declined" post!  Thanks!

Comment: @Lix: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration

Comment: Moderators have a textfield with autocomplete in the close dialog that allows them to migrate to any SE site. There might be some value in having a dedicated flag option for migration to any site, but I think we would need to address some of the more fundamental problems of migrations in general first, to avoid too many bad migrations.

Comment: @chr - please do not remove the "Possible Duplicate" links that are inserted automatically.  They are very relevant to the discussion here.

Comment: @lix can I *add* to them without frustrating the system?

Comment: Sure you can! If you want to add more links to relevant posts you can do so within the body of your post.  Those automatic messages should not be tampered with on any level.

Comment: @lix Very sorry. That was not clear from the remarks in the automated edit. I was editing the question for clarity when the automated edit happened and I assumed it was OK to remove it *as long as I incorporated the duplicate in the body*, as I did in edit n°5.

Comment: Its no big deal :) You can still detail those links in your post but just leave the automatic text.  I understand that you didn't specifically delete it maliciously and on purpose.  No harm done, I'm just letting you know that it is generally not cool to remove those dupe links...

Comment: +1.  While you re-asked one of the more common questions here, you put lots of effort into it.

Answer (score 2):

This will most probably be declined.

[There's a reason for the whole SE network not being there on the offtopic thingamajig](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96345/178438).

Also, [you don't know what's on-topic on the site you're migrating it to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128630/178438). Most mods ask the mods of the site they're migrating to before migration. Of course, a way to tell them which site you mean would be nice, but it's not necessary--you should be keeping that in the comments anyway (something along the lines of `Hi $name, I think your question would be a better fit on $site. This site deals with $topic. Please don't cross-post, a mod will migrate it for you.`). I guess an autocomplete text box with an additional optional textarea(for your rationale) would be OK, but I personally don't feel a need for it.

Note that on other sites we only have the option to flag as offtopic-->"is off topic", or flag offtopic-->"meta".

Comment: Great suggestion; I've [applied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941749/how-to-boost-module-cron-run-or-save#comment12915696_9941749) it.